# Error message: Variable doesn't exist

Tags: apex, trigger, error

I'm working on a trigger to update the account based on the first contact related to the parentaccount, but I'm having some problems when I try to compiling it. The message that are appearing is that  a variable doesn't exists, I'm noob in coding and would like to know what i'm doing wrong and also know how to avoid this kind of problem in the future...

```java
trigger AddDomain_AccountToContact on Account (before insert) {    
    List <Account> accList = new List <Account>();
    Set <Id> acc_Ids = new Set <Id>();
    
    for (Account account : trigger.new){
       Account oldAccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(account.id); 
       
        if(account.Unique_Domains__c != Null && (account.Ativo__c == True && oldAccount.Ativo__c == False 
         || account.Piloto_Zendesk__c == True && oldAccount.Piloto_Zendesk__c == False )){
             List<Account> accQueryList = [Select Id, Unique_Domains__c from Account where Id IN: acc_Ids]; 
         }
        
        for(Account a : accQueryList) {  
            String AccountDomain = '';
            List<Contact> contactList = [select Id, Domain__c, AccountId 
                                     from Contact WHERE AccountId in : acc_Ids];
            Integer contactListSize = contactList.size();
            Contact firstContact = contactList[0];
            AccountDomain = firstContact.Domain__c;
            a.Unique_Domains__c = AccountDomain;
            accList.add(a);
        }
    }
    update accList; 
}
```

The variable that doesn't exists is the "AccQueryList" inside on the loop "for(Account a : accQueryList)"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Queries inside of loops are bad, but we'll get to that later.

The issue here is that you defined `accQueryList` inside of an `if` block. Once you left that `if` block, the `accQueryList` was no longer in scope (and therefore cannot be used).

bad

```
if(<conditions>){
    // myList is defined inside the scope of this if block, and cannot be used outside
    //   of it
    List<SObject> myList = [query];
}

// This results in an error
for(SObject obj :myList){
}
```

good

```
// Define the list outside of the if
List<SObject> myList;
if(<conditions>){
    // You can populate the list inside of the if block
    mylist = [query];
}

// Because the list was not defined in an inner scope that we have left, we
//   can still use it here (and it'll still have the data populated from inside
//   the 'if', assuming we satisfied the conditions to enter that 'if' block
for(SObject obj :myList){
}
```

To get around the "query inside of a loop" problem, the typical approach is iterate-gather-query

```java
// Define a collection to hold the things you want to use to query
Set<Id> parentAcctIds = new Set<Id>();

// Iterate over your data
for(Account a :trigger.new){
    // Gather your target information
    parentAcctIds.add(a.ParentId);
}

// Then execute your query
// In this case, you can likely get away with simply storing the result in 
//   a Map<Id, Account>
// We can use a parent-child subquery to obtain the contacts related to an account.
// You may have to adjust it depending on what you use to define "the first contact"
Map<Id, Account> parentsWithContact = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Domain__c FROM Contacts ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :parentAcctIds]);
```

From there, you can iterate over your child accounts and get at the relevant data in the `parentsWithContact` map (assuming that your child accounts have `parentId` populated). It'd just be something like `String domain = parentsWithContact.get(acct.ParentId).Contacts[0].Domain__c;`

The details will differ depending on exactly what you're trying to do<sup>1</sup>, but that should give you a good jumping-off point.

<sup>1: if you're trying to get unique domain values, using a `Set<String>` and then using that to create a `List<String>` to feed into `String.join()` is the way I'd go about it. Your current code/description makes it hard to know if that's the correct thing to recommend though. Even if it were, that's probably something that should be its own question</sup>